# insert BLOB file from Local to DB

Tags: java, sql, oracle10g, blob

I am trying to allow users to choose a file from local hard disk and to insert it with java in a Oracle Data base as BLOB value.

The setBinaryStream did not allow big files.

with the setBlob I have no way to convert the file to a blob.

Is the import of a blob file from the DB then overwrite it the unique solution?.

Regards,
Haythem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*This is a suggestion that I've used before*

In essence a file **is** an array of bytes, what you can do is to read the file data and use `PreparedStatement.setBytes(index, byte[])` to store the data.

Hope this helps.

Comment: setBytes did not allow big files.

Comment: How big is the file? Why not increase the BLOB size?

Comment: for 1 kB  is ok for 1 MB not.

Comment: I store 5MB file in MySQL using Blob with not problems (and I use `setBytes()`.

Comment: I am using oracle DB perhapes is this made a difference.

Comment: @Haythem, it shouldn't, make sure your Blob size can accept files >= 1MB.

Comment: I defined the File as Oracle.sql.BLOB and it works.
with java.sql.blob is not working

Answer (score 1):

You need to read the file as any byte array. This byte array can be assigned to Oracle BLOB column.