# How to save image to mySQL which the user have uploaded

Tags: java, mysql, image

I want to tell me How to save image to the mySQL after the user uploaded.
**HINT : using NetBeans GUI Builder**


This my code for choose image:

```
private void btnJFileChooserActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                
    JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
    int result = fc.showOpenDialog(null);
    if (result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        File file = fc.getSelectedFile();
        try {
            image2.setIcon(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(file)));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

This capture for Setter and Getter: 
http://up07.s-oman.net/DVMGa.png

This capture for save button:
http://up07.s-oman.net/P2slSGkcj.png

Comment: See the answer [to this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6472233/can-i-store-images-in-mysql) before continuing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try saving is as a blob? Here's the link to solution on Stack Overflow: [insert BLOB file from Local to DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4283777/insert-blob-file-from-local-to-db)

Comment: how to define picture in setter and getter method??